# Save class in NSUserDefaults/UserDefaults in PCL and to use it in Xamarin.iOS/Droid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have implemented a login service and getting some user related data as a class in ViewModel.

Now I want to save this class somewhere and want to access it later. In iOS best place to this would have been NSUserDefaults. But I have to do it in Xamarin. I am using MVVMCross in my app and has PCL implemented.

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin

Comment: Can I save a class here? I don't see this option in the list of Data that can be stored.

Comment: You would typically serialize whatever data you were working with and then save it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the [SettingsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) will do exactly what you want and very simple to use. Although, I have always just made my own settings and used `NSUserDefaults` for iOS in the past with `Newtonsoft.Json`.

```cs
public class iOSSettings : ISettings
{
    public ViewModel CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return DeserializeSetting<ViewModel>("CurrentViewModel"); }
        set { SerializeSetting("CurrentViewModel", value); }
    }

    private static T DeserializeSetting<T>(string key)
            where T : class
    {
        string json = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(key);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            return null;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }

    private static void SerializeSetting(string key, object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(string.Empty, key);
        }
        else
        {
            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value), key);
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
    }
}
```

For Android:

```cs
public class AndroidSettings : ISettings
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    private ISharedPreferences _preferences;
    private ISharedPreferencesEditor _editor;

    public AndroidSettings(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ViewModel CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return GetObject<ViewModel>("CurrentViewModel"); }
        set { Put("CurrentViewModel", value); }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        //Commit changes and dispose
        if (_editor != null)
        {
            _editor.Commit();
            _editor.Dispose();
            _editor = null;
        }
        if (_preferences != null)
        {
            _preferences.Dispose();
            _preferences = null;
        }
    }

    private T GetObject<T>(string key)
        where T : class
    {
        //Use a local instance of preferences for "Get"
        using (var preferences = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(_context))
        {
            string json = preferences.GetString(key, string.Empty);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                return null;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }
    }

    private void Put(string key, object value)
    {
        CheckPreferences();

        _editor.PutString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        _editor.Commit();
    }

    private void CheckPreferences()
    {
        //Create preferences & editor if needed
        if (_preferences == null)
            _preferences = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(_context);
        if (_editor == null)
            _editor = _preferences.Edit();
    }
}
```